# Proving the Archimedean Property of reals and NIP (Nested Interval Property) using MCT

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm doing **exercise 2.4.4** in the book `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abbott. I'd like to ask, if my proof (especially part (a) of the question) is rigorous and technically correct.

> (a) In a previous section, we used the Axiom of Completeness(AoC) to prove the Archimedean property of real numbers $\mathbf{R}$. Show that the Monotone Convergence Theorem can also be used to prove the Archimedean property without making any use of AoC.
>
> (b) Use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to supply a proof for the Nested Interval Property that doesn't make use of the AoC.
>
> These two results would suggest that we could have used the Monotone Convergence Theorem in place of the AoC as our starting axiom for building a proper theory of the real numbers.

***Proof.***

(a) The Archimedean property states that, $\mathbf{N}$ is an unbounded set that sits in $\mathbf{R}$. Given any real number $x$, there exists $n \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $x < n$.

By contradiction, let us assume that $\mathbf{N}$ is bounded subset of $\mathbf{R}$. Then, there exists an upper bound $x \in \mathbf{R}$, such that $n < x$ for all natural numbers $n \in \mathbf{N}$. The natural numbers are recursively defined using the sequence $x_{n+1} = 1 + x_n$. This is a monotonically increasing sequence. Hence, $\mathbf{N}$ is monotonic increasing and bounded, by monotone convergence theorem, the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent. Let $\lim x_{n+1} = \lim x_{n} = x$. Taking limits on both sides, we have:
\begin{align*}
    x &= 1 + x \\
    0 &= 1
\end{align*}

This is a false statement and violates Peano's axioms. Moreover, we cannot find an interval $V_\epsilon(x)$ such that the values of the sequence $(x_n)$ will eventually lie in this interval. So, $(x_n)$ is not a convergent sequence $\implies$ $(x_n)$ is unbounded $\implies$ $\exists n \in \mathbf{N}$, such that $x < n$ for all reals $x$.

(b) The nested interval property states that the real number line $\mathbf{R}$ contains no gaps. I reproduce the statement of NIP for completeness.

> For each $n \in \mathbf{N}$, assume that we are given a closed interval $I_n = [a_n, b_n] = \{x \in \mathbf{R}: a_n \le x \le b_n\}$. Assume also that each $I_n$ contains $I_{n+1}$. Then, the resulting nested sequence of closed intervals
> \begin{align*}
>     I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq I_4 \ldots
> \end{align*}

> have a non-empty intersection; that is
> \begin{align*}
>     \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \ne \phi
> \end{align*}

Since, $I_n \supseteq I_{n+1}$, that is $[a_n,b_n] \supseteq [a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$, the sequence consisting of the left hand end-points $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots, a_n$; $(a_n)$ is monotonically increasing. Moreover, the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $b_n$. By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the sequence is convergent and $\lim_n (a_n) = s = \sup \{a_n : n \in \mathbf{N}\}$.

Since, $s$ is an upper bound for the sequence $(a_n)$, $a_n \le s$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Moreover, as $s$ is the least upper bound $s \le b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Consequently, $a_n \le s \le b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Thus, $s \in I_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$, and the countable intersection of these intervals is non-empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’ve done is mostly correct, but there are a few fairly minor problems. First, your derivation of the contradiction in (a) could be made clearer. Once you have $x_{n+1}=1+x_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, you can write

$$x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x_n)=1+\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1+x\,;$$

this makes it very clear how you deduce that $x=1+x$ and hence that $0=1$. You should stop there: the remainder of that last paragraph is unnecessary. Moreover, part of it is false: it is simply not true that there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x<n$ for all reals $x$. It isn’t even true that there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\le n$ for all reals $x$: just take $x=n+1$ to get a counterexample.

The idea in (b) is fine, but some of what you’ve written is rather sloppy. For instance, you write that

> … the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $b_n$.

Here you are using the letter $n$ to mean two different things in the same statement: in $(a_n)$ it’s an index that runs over all positive integers, and in $b_n$ it refers to some specific index. What you mean is that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, the sequence $\langle a_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is bounded above by $b_n$. In particular, it is bounded above, so it converges to some $s=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\in\Bbb R$. The remainder of that last paragraph is fine.